# Unable to use Hyper-V to make a virtual machine

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v

I am currently unable to create a virtual machine with Hyper-V and I am just left with this screen:

[image: screencap]

Any help on the issue would be appreciated.

I have already made sure that I have enabled SVM in the BIOS.

I have also made sure that I have enabled Hyper-V in the Windows features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screen only shows the Windows Management Console, it's not Hyper-V management screen.

To access Hyper-V from where you're stuck:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
2. In the left-side list, select **Hyper-V Management**
3. Click the **Add** button in the middle
4. Click **Ok**
5. Double-click **Hyper-V Management** on the left-side panel then click on your computer's name

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.